# Pandas selecting columns to plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I'm taking an online course and I'm stuck at a part where trying to plot based on column name. It's not part of the course to do this so there's not much guidance.

```
#column year rename
gdp_df.rename(columns=lambda x: x + "_GDP", inplace=True)
selfemployed_df.rename(columns=lambda x: x + "_SE", inplace=True)
salaried_df.rename(columns=lambda x: x + "_S", inplace=True)

#country column rename
gdp_df.rename(columns={"GDP per capita_GDP":"country"},inplace=True)
selfemployed_df.rename(columns={"Total self-employed (%)_SE":"country"}, inplace=True)
salaried_df.rename(columns={"Total salaried employees (%)_S":"country"}, inplace=True)

#merge the dataframe
merge_df = salaried_df.merge(gdp_df.merge(selfemployed_df, left_on='country', right_on='country', how='inner'), left_on='country', right_on='country',how='inner')
```

Now I'm stuck at the step where I plot by _S, _GDP or _SE. How would I do plot group by where column name contains _S or _GDP or _SE? Am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, wrong... You can do things always in many ways...
However, if you want to merge all your datasets into one and ask yourself how to extract a subset of columns depending on those suffixes, you could do the following:

```
S_cols = merge_df.columns[merge_df.columns.str.endswith('_S')]
```

Then

```
merge_df[S_cols]
```

would give you a dataframe with only the columns ending with '_S' inside.

One way to plot would then simply be

```
merge_df[S_cols].plot()
```

You can imagine the same with the other endings.

What I do not understand: as you merge the dataframes by yourself, you already have the separated dataframes at hand, i.e.: `gdp_df`, `selfemployed_df` and `salaried_df`. So what's the roblem here?

Comment: I merged it so the data matches all 3 dataframes after the Joins